# How do I permanently store input from an HTML text field into a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var guess;
    $('#submit').on("click", function() {
        guess = $('#guess-value').val();
        $("#value").text(guess);
        alert(guess);
    });
    alert(guess);
});
```

## HTML

```
<div id='game'>
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='guess-value' placeholder='1-100'></input>    
        <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h4 id='guess-count'>Attempts left: <span id="attempts">6</span></h4>       
</div>

<h4 id='checker'>The value entered is <span id="value">?</span></h4>
```

I've provided snippets of my HTML and jQuery code above. I am trying to store a number that has been entered into a text field, into a jQuery variable called `guess` after pressing a submit button.

The following happens occurs:
When I enter a number into the field and press submit, I get an alert showing the value I entered. After closing the event I get another alert that is supposed to show the value of 'guess' and the value is undefined.

This happens even though I declared the variable `guess` outside of the click event. Why is this and how do I permanently store the value?

Comment: the 2nd alert is shown before you submit, not after; it's only because the page reloads that it seems later. if you didn't submit, you should see only one alert each click, and one upon ready(), which would show undefined as a value hasn't been set yet at boot-time.

Comment: what do you mean permanently? because when page is loaded or unloaded you will lose any data in the javascript variable.

Comment: I want to store the number entered so I can determine if it's equal to some random number. It's a guessing game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `<form>` element to ask for user input. The problem with a form, is that when it submits, it wants to navigate away from (or refresh) the page. When the page refreshes, all js is lost.

Simple fix: don't use a form (you can use a DIV instead).

Alternatively, you can tell the form to NOT do its default action of submitting by using `event.preventDefault()`:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCF96/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id='game'>
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='guess-value' placeholder='1-100'></input>
        <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
     <h4 id='guess-count'>Attempts left: <span id="attempts">6</span></h4> 
</div>

<h4 id='checker'>The value entered is <span id="value">?</span></h4>

<input type="button" id="myButt" value="Show Value" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
var guess;
$('#submit').on("click", function (evnt) {
    guess = $('#guess-value').val();
    $("#value").text(guess);
    alert(guess);
    evnt.preventDefault();
});

$('#myButt').click(function(){
   alert( guess ); 
});
```

Further Notes:

Note that the 2nd `alert(guess)` in your posted code will occur immediately upon document.ready. I mean, *immediately* -- as soon as the DOM is ready. Before anything has been put into **guess**. *That is why it returns **undefined.***

That is probably not what you want. Code example above adds a button to allow you to view that variable's contents when desired.

Comment: Wow! First time in my life I see that `evnt.preventDefault();` isn't first line in the function's body!! Wow! Amazing

Comment: To be honest, I often put it as the first line in the function... *so I don't forget to code it* ... if others have DRAM for brains (like I do) then that may account for why it is usually first.

Answer (score 1):

The function : `$("#value").text(guess)` is not corret in this case, replace it with :

```
$("#value").empty().append(guess);
```

you should wait to be .[ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in order to submit();

give me feedback please. enjoy :)

Comment: B'jour - great contribution, Jean, but not completely accurate. It is not necessary to first empty the span before re-populating it. `$("#value").text(guess);` will overwrite any existing contents. Try it out with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCF96/1/)

Comment: Doesn't it do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The 'guess' variable is out of the click event handler but it's in the ready event handler; So the second alert box will be shown exactly once when the page is loaded. It will then be undefined. The click events will occur later.

Comment: Yes the second alert box is shown when the page is loaded and it is undefined. Then the alert box from the click event shows the value I entered into the box when I press submit. After closing that, the second alert box is shown again with the value undefined, meaning the value I entered into the box wasn't stored.